# Keras Sequential API is replacing every layer with abstract class 'ModuleWrapper' after building model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a sequential model with Tensorflow's (2.5) Keras API.
After training my model I've found out that I was not able to save my model because the config for Layer `ModuleWrapper` was not implemented, which brought a lot of confusion to me, because I was **not** using any Layer called 'ModuleWrapper'. I also did not use any self-made Layers.

After a lot of testing I figured out that the Keras Sequential API somehow does not recognize it's own Layers and replaces them with the *Abstract Class(?)* ModuleWrapper.

Any help on why this happens would be greatly appreciated!

### Imports

```
import tensorflow as tf  # version 2.5

from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU, Softmax
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, SeparableConv2D
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Reshape, Activation
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
```

### The Model

```
def create_model():

  input_shape = (180, 18, 1)

  data_format = 'channels_last'
  batch_norm_axis = -1  # must be 1 if data_format = 'channels_first'
  conv_activation = 'relu'
  padding = 'same'

  model = keras.Sequential(name="CPDP_4h_1dim")

  model.add(BatchNormalization(name="batch0"))

  model.add(Conv2D(name="Conv1", filters=64, input_shape=input_shape, kernel_size=(6, 6), padding=padding, activation=conv_activation, data_format=data_format))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name="batch1", axis=batch_norm_axis))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(name="pool1", pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout1", rate=0.35))

  model.add(Conv2D(name="Conv2", filters=128, kernel_size=(6, 6), padding=padding, activation=conv_activation, data_format=data_format))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name="batch2", axis=batch_norm_axis))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(name="pool2", pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout2", rate=0.35))

  model.add(Conv2D(name="Conv3", filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=padding, activation=conv_activation, data_format=data_format))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name="batch3", axis=batch_norm_axis))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(name="pool3", pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout3", rate=0.15))

  model.add(Conv2D(name="Conv4", filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=padding, activation=conv_activation, data_format=data_format))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name="batch4", axis=batch_norm_axis))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(name="pool4", pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout4", rate=0.25))

  model.add(Conv2D(name="Conv5", filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=padding, activation=conv_activation, data_format=data_format))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name="batch5", axis=batch_norm_axis))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(name="pool5", pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1)))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout5", rate=0.25))


  # [batch, width, height, features]
  # width are timesteps
  # LSTM expectationms: [batch, timesteps, feature] 
  # --> transform to [batch, width, (height,features)]
  model.add(Reshape((175, 13*256), input_shape=(None, 175, 13, 256),  name="reshape_for_lstm"))
  model.add(LSTM(name="lstm1", units=512, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))
  model.add(LSTM(name="lstm2", units=256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.15))

  model.add(Flatten(name="flatten1"))

  model.add(Dense(name="dense1", units=256))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout5", rate=0.15))

  model.add(Dense(name="dense15", units=256))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout51", rate=0.15))
  
  model.add(Dense(name="dense2", units=128))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout6", rate=0.15))

  model.add(Dense(name="dense3", units=64))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(name="dropout7", rate=0.15))

  model.add(Dense(name="dense4", units=3))
  model.add(Activation('softmax'))
  return model
```

```
model = create_model()
model.build(input_shape=(None, 180, 18, 1))
```

### Using `model.summary()`

```
Model: "CPDP_4h_1dim"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
module_wrapper_472 (ModuleWr (None, 180, 18, 1)        4         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_473 (ModuleWr (None, 180, 18, 64)       2368      
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_474 (ModuleWr (None, 180, 18, 64)       256       
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_475 (ModuleWr (None, 179, 17, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_476 (ModuleWr (None, 179, 17, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_477 (ModuleWr (None, 179, 17, 128)      295040    
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_478 (ModuleWr (None, 179, 17, 128)      512       
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_479 (ModuleWr (None, 178, 16, 128)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_480 (ModuleWr (None, 178, 16, 128)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_481 (ModuleWr (None, 178, 16, 128)      147584    
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_482 (ModuleWr (None, 178, 16, 128)      512       
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_483 (ModuleWr (None, 177, 15, 128)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_484 (ModuleWr (None, 177, 15, 128)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_485 (ModuleWr (None, 177, 15, 256)      295168    
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_486 (ModuleWr (None, 177, 15, 256)      1024      
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_487 (ModuleWr (None, 176, 14, 256)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_488 (ModuleWr (None, 176, 14, 256)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_489 (ModuleWr (None, 176, 14, 256)      590080    
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_490 (ModuleWr (None, 176, 14, 256)      1024      
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_491 (ModuleWr (None, 175, 13, 256)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_492 (ModuleWr (None, 175, 13, 256)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_493 (ModuleWr (None, 175, 3328)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_494 (ModuleWr (None, 175, 512)          7866368   
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_495 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               787456    
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_496 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_497 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               65792     
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_498 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_499 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_500 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               65792     
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_501 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_502 (ModuleWr (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_503 (ModuleWr (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_504 (ModuleWr (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_505 (ModuleWr (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_506 (ModuleWr (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_507 (ModuleWr (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_508 (ModuleWr (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_509 (ModuleWr (None, 3)                 195       
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_510 (ModuleWr (None, 3)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 10,160,327
Trainable params: 10,158,661
Non-trainable params: 1,666
_________________________________________________________________
```

### Using `print(model.layers)`

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42845faf90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840f7f90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840f2c90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840f2b90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840f2490>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42843426d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840e3710>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840f9c90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840fd590>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840fb310>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840f9a90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840ed3d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840edf90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840ed290>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840e7a50>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840e73d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840e4690>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840ddf10>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840c8b10>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f4284097290>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f4284097690>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f4284097950>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840a2050>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840a2ad0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840a2e50>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840aa350>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840aaad0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840aaf10>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840aad50>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840b6710>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840fb990>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840b63d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840b6a10>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840b69d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840c1110>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840c1e90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f42840c12d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f428404e1d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.ModuleWrapper at 0x7f428404eb10>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import your modules as follows, also don't mix `tf 2.x` with old standalone `keras` in the same import.

```
import tensorflow as tf  # version 2.5
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU, Softmax
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, SeparableConv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Reshape, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
```

Apart from this, all the layer names inside the model definition should contain a unique name. But in your model `dropout5` appears twice, so consider this.