# Conv layer, No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I try to train mnist dataset but I got an error like this:

```
No gradients provided for any variable: ['module_wrapper/conv2d/kernel:0', 
'module_wrapper/conv2d/bias:0', 'module_wrapper_2/conv2d_1/kernel:0', 
'module_wrapper_2/conv2d_1/bias:0', 'module_wrapper_5/dense/kernel:0',
'module_wrapper_5/dense/bias:0', 'module_wrapper_6/dense_1/kernel:0',
'module_wrapper_6/dense_1/bias:0'].
```

My fit code:

`self.model.fit(x = self.datas.trainImages, y = self.datas.trainLabels, batch_size = self.datas.batch_size, epochs =self.datas.epochs)`

Here the variables:

```
self.datas.trainImages = numpy.stack([cv2.imread(image1)],[cv2.imread(image2), dtype = float64],[cv2.imread(image3)])

self.datas.trainLabels = numpy.stack([0,1,2], dtype = int32)
```

Also if I print model.summary(), and it is lenet model:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
module_wrapper (ModuleWrappe (None, 28, 28, 32)        320
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_1 (ModuleWrap (None, 14, 14, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_2 (ModuleWrap (None, 14, 14, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_3 (ModuleWrap (None, 7, 7, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_4 (ModuleWrap (None, 3136)              0
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_5 (ModuleWrap (None, 500)               1568500
_________________________________________________________________
module_wrapper_6 (ModuleWrap (None, 10)                5010
=================================================================
Total params: 1,592,326
Trainable params: 1,592,326
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

There are no layers named Conv2D but I added them,

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(500))
model.add(layers.Dense(self.datas.classCount,activation='softmax'))
```

When I research about the problem, google and stackoverflow says add labels into fit function but I already added them.

**UPDATE 1**

you can try this codes to run it :

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow.keras.losses


parameters = parameters
datas = datas
model = Sequential()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
loss = tensorflow.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(name = 'CategoricalCrossentropy', from_logits = True)
metrics = tensorflow.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name = 'CategoricalAccuracy')


model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))        
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(500))
model.add(layers.Dense(self.datas.classCount,activation='softmax'))

trainImages = numpy.stack([[cv2.imread(image1)],[cv2.imread(image2)],[cv2.imread(image3)]], dtype = float64)
#All images is belong to mnist dataset. I read them from a folder and append to list, then convert the dataset list into numpy.stack
trainLabels = numpy.stack([0,1,2], dtype = int32)
model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer = optimizer, metrics = metrics)
model.fit(x = trainImages, y = trainLabels, batch_size = 2, epochs =1)
```

Comment: You train only on 3 images ? To compute a gradient descent the size of the train dataset must be higher than the batch size.

Comment: @EricMarchand actually it is not 3, I just tried to make you imagine the dataset format. My codes have a lot of steps and I just tried to make it easy.

Comment: Please add the imports to your question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried to maket it easier, you can see it in update 1.

Comment: Those are not all the imports, layers is not defined in your code.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy But why, I imported layers with `from tensorflow.python.keras import layers` and used them like `model.add(layers.Flatten())`

Comment: Where are you calling `model.compile`?

Comment: The problem is that you have these ModuleWrapper in your model summary and that happens when you mix imports between keras and tf.keras, so I do  not think these are the actual imports you are using. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67743764/keras-sequential-api-is-replacing-every-layer-with-abstract-class-modulewrapper

Comment: @AloneTogether I added it, all of them are okay in my code, I guess I forgot to add it to here.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for it, I fixed it but error is same. But layers's name was changed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example based on your code but with the MNIST dataset, and just in case you didn't know, you should either use a softmax function on your output layer or set the `from_logits` parameter of your loss function to `True`, but **not** both.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(name = 'CategoricalCrossentropy')
metrics = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name = 'CategoricalAccuracy')

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))        
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=3,strides=1,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)

print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer = optimizer, metrics = metrics)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 64, epochs = 1)
```

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling  (None, 14, 14, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 14, 14, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling  (None, 7, 7, 64)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten_3 (Flatten)         (None, 3136)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 500)               1568500   
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 10)                5010      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,592,326
Trainable params: 1,592,326
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
938/938 [==============================] - 8s 8ms/step - loss: 24.1966 - CategoricalAccuracy: 0.1079
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f831b6d0a50>
```

Comment: I am so mixed. Actually from_logits was false. I tried to run your codes, it works. I converted my labels with tf.keras.utils.to_categorical function, but it does not work again. I think my problem is about input values because before this post, I had some problems about input,  [here the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219700/failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupported-object-type-numpy-ndarr).

Comment: I think for (28,28,32), 32 is filter number.

Comment: When I print your codes summary, I get shape for first conv layer like (2,32,32,32) two 32 is shape of the images, another 32 is filter number, and 2 is batch size. But in model.summary() 2 is None, like (None, 28,28,32)

Comment: I used tf.expand_dims for dataset, I used model.built(input_shape = (28,28,1)) but none of them works

Comment: Thanks for everything, I will try to handle it.

Comment: Updated answer with a model using the MNIST dataset.

Comment: After your comment, I copied and pasted your codes to my codes. And changed my all variables with yours step by step. Then I relaized optimizer causes to error, and looked at optimizer structure. It was my misatake, I gave wrong value to learning_rate. After all of these, yes it works. Thanks for everything, sorry for late reply. I was working and I forgot to type here.